# AVCaptureSession and Cocos2d-x on macOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, avfoundation, cocos2d-x

I'm implementing gameplay recording feature into cross platform Cocos2d-x game. I managed to implement those features for iOS and Android but I'm struggling to get good performance on macOS. I have implemented succesfully gameplay recording using glReadPixels function but performance is very low. I'm getting about 10-15 fps on my Macbook Pro. I was trying to implement AVCaptureSession to record whole screen and then crop required area just like in the AVScreenShack sample from Apple but I'm getting Cocos2d-x Renderer errors.

Error log looks like this:

```
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.cpp postStep 458
OpenGL error 0x0506 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp applyFBO 445
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
OpenGL error 0x0506 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp applyFBO 445
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCRenderer.cpp saveRenderState 161
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCTextureAtlas.cpp drawNumberOfQuads 691
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCRenderer.cpp restoreRenderState 192
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.cpp postStep 458
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.cpp postStep 458
OpenGL error 0x0506 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp applyFBO 445
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
OpenGL error 0x0506 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp applyFBO 445
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
FrameBuffer Status Error 33305
OpenGL error 0x0501 in /Users/milosz/Documents/job/butterflix/blix/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCRenderer.cpp saveRenderState 161
```

My first thought was that the AVCaptureSession uses NSOpengGLContext to render frames so I checked if the context has changed but it didn't. I also was trying CVOpenGLTextureCache accordingly to the method I'm using on iOS but without success.

However when I'm running AVScreenShack example while playing my game it records whole screen and doesn't mess with the Cocos2d-x renderer. I think that is because both apps running on separate main threads and therefore there is no some kind of race condition occuring. Can I replicate this kind of behaviour in single Mac app? Or there is any other method to record Cocos2d-x gameplay with reasonable performance on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue but with Qt app. After calling [AVCaptureSession startRunning] my OpenGL stopped working properly.
In my case current NSOpenGLContext was `nil` after calling startRunning.
So solution for me was:

```
QOpenGLContext *currentContext = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
QSurface *currentSurface = currentContext->surface();
[m_Session startRunning];
currentContext->makeCurrent(currentSurface);
```